# how to solve database configuration error in joomla?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

i have installed joomla in xampp when i configuring database it shows the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9' at line 11 SQL=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `d3vm0_usergroups` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key', `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Adjacency List Reference Id', `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set lft.', `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set rgt.', `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `idx_usergroup_parent_title_lookup` (`parent_id`,`title`), KEY `idx_usergroup_title_lookup` (`title`), KEY `idx_usergroup_adjacency_lookup` (`parent_id`), KEY `idx_usergroup_nested_set_lookup` (`lft`,`rgt`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9

Table 'testone.d3vm0_usergroups' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `d3vm0_usergroups` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `title`) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 18, 'Public'), (2, 1, 8, 15, 'Registered'), (3, 2, 9, 14, 'Author'), (4, 3, 10, 13, 'Editor'), (5, 4, 11, 12, 'Publisher'), (6, 1, 4, 7, 'Manager'), (7, 6, 5, 6, 'Administrator'), (8, 1, 16, 17, 'Super Users'), (9, 1, 2, 3, 'Guest')
```

Comment: check `testone` in phpmyadmin that it has table `d3vm0_usergroups` or not

Comment: testone? have you installed a new version of joomla? or you just migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CREATE TABLE` failed , so it can not execute `INSERT` statement, because there is no table to `INSERT`.

`CREATE TABLE` gets an error on `USING BTREE` statement. i am not sure but perhaps this works.
`CREATE...(lft,rgt) USING BTREE (lft,rgt))...`
Also you can not insert into auto-increment column

Comment: If it is a BTREE problem that means the mysql version is too low.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue occur due to incompatible version of Mysql

To solve this issue follow These steps :-

Go to : C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla32\installation\sql\mysql 
or where you install xampp

remove "USING BTREE" from joomla.sql file and save.

This is working for me.

Hope This will Help You.